# Simple gSoap Server and Client with SSL

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, gsoap

The call to `soap_ssl_accept` always results in the error `SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol`. I made it simple as possible and turned of server authentication by setting `SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION`. I broke it down to following server and client code. Can you help me getting a working example?

Server Side:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "ADService.nsmap" // get namespace bindings
#include "stdsoap2.h"
#include "soapH.h"

int ns1__add(struct soap *soap, xsd__int a, xsd__int b, xsd__int& c) {
    c = a + b;
    return SOAP_OK;
}


int main() {
    int m, s;
    struct soap soap;
    soap_ssl_init(); // init OpenSSL (just once)
    soap_init(&soap);
    if (soap_ssl_server_context(&soap,
        SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION,
        NULL, // keyfile: required when server must authenticate to clients
        NULL, // password to read the key file
        NULL, // optional cacert file to store trusted certificates
        NULL, // optional capath to directory with trusted certificates
        NULL, // DH file name or DH key len bits 
        NULL, // if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data
        NULL)) {
        soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    m = soap_bind(&soap, NULL, 18000, 100); // use port 18000
    if (m < 0) {
        soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket connection successful: master socket = %d\n", m);
    for (;;) {
        s = soap_accept(&soap);
        printf("Socket connection successful: slave socket = %d\n", s);
        if (s < 0) {
            soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
            break;
        }
        if (soap_ssl_accept(&soap))
            soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
        else
            soap_serve(&soap);
        soap_destroy(&soap);
        soap_end(&soap);
        soap_free(&soap); // done and free context  
    }
    soap_done(&soap); /* deallocates SSL context */
    return 0;
}
```

Client Side:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "soapH.h" // obtain the generated stub 
#include "ADService.nsmap" // obtain the namespace mapping table 

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    soap soap;
    soap_ssl_init();
    soap_init(&soap);
    if (soap_ssl_client_context(&soap,
       SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION,
       NULL, // keyfile: required only when client must authenticate to server
       NULL, // password to read the key file (not used with GNUTLS)
       NULL, // cacert file to store trusted certificates
       NULL, // capath to directory with trusted certificates
       NULL  // if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness
    )) {
       soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
       return 1;
    }
    xsd__int result;
    if(soap_call_ns1__add(
        &soap, "localhost:18000", 0, 1, 2, result) != SOAP_OK) {
        soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
        soap_print_fault_location(&soap, stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Result = %d", result);
    soap_destroy(&soap);
    soap_end(&soap);
    soap_done(&soap);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on server side:

> Socket connection successful: master socket = 1916
>   Socket connection successful: slave socket = 1912
>   Error 30 fault: SOAP-ENV:Server [no subcode]
>   "SSL_ERROR_SSL
>   error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown > protocol"
>   Detail: SSL_accept() failed in soap_ssl_accept()
>   Press any key to continue

Comment: Is it possible to capture tcpdump and see whats going out from client?

Comment: It often means plaintext HTML is served over the port rather than HTTPS. That is, the server sends `<! DOCTYPE=...>` and the client tries to interpret it as a SSL/TLS record. Use `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -tls1 -servername <server> -debug` to confirm. You will see ASCII in the client reads (rather than binary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `soap_call_ns1__add` with the hostname `https://localhost:18000` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer. But might help. How I ended up with error what you see:

> 3077928696:error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:628

It happens when on successful TCP connection with server,client sends in ill-formed client_hello message. I basically in my test sent junk bytes after TCP connection.

Capture tcpdump b/w server and client and see whats going out from client.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. This can be my next step. Before I will debug into the gSoap function.